# unexpected TRUE return value from GetAttr on error

Tags: vba

With this code:

```
If GetAttr(sFullPath) And vbDirectory then msgbox "is a directory"
```

- Passing  an existant sFullPath (like "C:\") the AND returns 16
- Passing a non existant sFullPath (like "X:\") the AND returns a runtime error 76

As far as I see, the IF test considers 0 as FALSE and any number greater than 0 as TRUE.

The question is: why is the msgbox displayed with a non existant sFullPath? it's like if GetAttr returns an unexpected number greater than 0 together with the run-time error...

Comment: Do you have `On Error` statements around this call? Because a runtime error only allows to Debug or End.

Comment: Yes I have an "On Error Resume Next"

Comment: Then you have undefined behavior. You must do an `On Error Goto` to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, as Paul suggested in a deleted comment, GetAttr returns -1 if on error and (-1 AND vbDirectory) is considered TRUE in the IF test.

Note: I used "On Error Resume Next"